# Checking if subprocess call executed successfully

Tags: python, subprocess

So I am still teaching myself Python and I wanted to created a small script for my server that will tell me if my HDD is mounted and if not to mount it for me when I sign in. (I have it in `~/.bashrc`).

The problem I am facing is this:

```
try:
    with open('/media/Hitachi/mountfile.txt', 'r') as f:
        print(f.readline())
except:
        print('HDD is not mounted')
        if not os.path.exists('/media/Hitachi/media'):
                print('Attempting to mount HDD')
                script = subprocess.call('mountscript.sh', shell=True)
```

How can I find out if `mountscript.sh` succeeded or not?

Comment: iirc subprocess.call returns the exit code.. so you could just check if script==0 ?

Answer (score 4):

[subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) method returns the `returncode` of the process so you can check that to see whether the call succeeded.

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
0
>>> subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

why not a simple if/else statement and use check_call

```
if os.path.exists('/media/Hitachi/mountfile.txt'):
    print("it's mounted")
else:
    print('HDD is not mounted')
    if not os.path.exists('/media/Hitachi/media'):
        print('Attempting to mount HDD')
        script = subprocess.check_call(['mountscript.sh','2>file.txt'], shell=True)
```

Regardless of that, the moral of the story is    don't forget the brackets around the command arguments to subprocess.call() or check_call()

Comment: Because I am trying to teach myself other methods, so even if this is less simplistic, its a learning exercise for myself.

Comment: "The try-expect construct is only used for handling exceptions that modules can throw. It should never be used as an alternative to if-else."  http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html

Comment: Thank you :), by the way, is there a way to pipe unix errors that moutnscript my encounter to a text file?

Comment: ... which probably doesn't work as intended or ist at least bad style: if you use `shell=True`, you should use a string, not a list of strings. Better do `with open("file.txt", "w") as f: script = subprocess.check_call(['mountscript.sh'], stderr=f)`